# Is there OpenCV colormap in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am aware of  [Matlab, matplotlib style colormap in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html) . The documentation explains its usage for C++. I was wondering if such an option exists for python using cv2 as well. I googled a lot to find nothing. I am aware of matplotlib's colormap option that I can use but if cv2 provides such option, I can remove the overhead of converting the matplotlib colormaps to opencv images. Its clumsy. I require it for my project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For OpenCV 2.4.11, `applyColorMap` works in Python (even though the [2.4.11 docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html) still list only C++):

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
imC = cv2.applyColorMap(im, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

See also [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28559208/1628638).

Answer (score 2):

shame, it looks like it did not make it into the python api yet.  but you could have a look at the implementation in modules/contrib/src/colormap.cpp,  e.g. the jetmap is only a lookup-table, you could just steal it

Comment: I was really hoping that it was already implemented...... Very well, I will get on with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sadly OpenCV doesn't have any colorMap but you can write one. Not that difficult.

```
class ColorMap:
    startcolor = ()
    endcolor = ()
    startmap = 0
    endmap = 0
    colordistance = 0
    valuerange = 0
    ratios = []    

    def __init__(self, startcolor, endcolor, startmap, endmap):
        self.startcolor = np.array(startcolor)
        self.endcolor = np.array(endcolor)
        self.startmap = float(startmap)
        self.endmap = float(endmap)
        self.valuerange = float(endmap - startmap)
        self.ratios = (self.endcolor - self.startcolor) / self.valuerange

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        color = tuple(self.startcolor + (self.ratios * (value - self.startmap)))
        return (int(color[0]), int(color[1]), int(color[2]))
```

Comment: can you explain how this should work with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get the previous examples of applyColorMap in Python to work.
Thought I share.
I apologize for the 'fat'.
If your video camera isn't being recognized, or have mult cameras, substitute '1' for '0'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frameWidth = 940
frameHeight = 680
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)  # 3=width, 4=height
cap.set(4, frameHeight)

while True:
    success, imgColor, = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(imgColor, (frameWidth, frameHeight))  # if want to resize frame
    
    # ORIG IMG
    cv2.moveWindow("img", 0, 0)  # relocate shift reposition move so frame is at top left corner of monitor
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    
    # COLOR ENHANCED
    cv2.moveWindow("imgColor", frameWidth, 0)  # relocate shift reposition move to side by side
    # COLORMAP_AUTUMN = 0
    # COLORMAP_BONE = 1
    # COLORMAP_COOL = 8
    # COLORMAP_HOT = 11
    # COLORMAP_HSV = 9
    # COLORMAP_JET = 2
    # COLORMAP_OCEAN = 5
    # COLORMAP_PINK = 10
    # COLORMAP_RAINBOW = 4
    # COLORMAP_SPRING = 7
    # COLORMAP_SUMMER = 6
    # COLORMAP_WINTER = 3
    cv2.imshow("imgColor", cv2.applyColorMap(imgColor, 3))  # change the last variable in here

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```