# Use different colormap with one channel image - cv2.imshow()

Tags: python, opencv, colormap

When I use this method with an 1 channel image, it's shown in grayscale. Is there a way to use other color maps (not grayscale) when showing an 1 channel image? If there is, it means grayscale is the default for imshow when working with an image with only 1 channel? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there OpenCV colormap in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043411/is-there-opencv-colormap-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot apply a color map in Python/OpenCV cv2.imshow like you can with Mathplotlib pyplot.  But you can create a color map and apply it to your grayscale image using cv2.LUT to change your grayscale image into a colored image that you can display with cv2.imshow.

Please see the documentation for cv2.imshow at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

Answer (score 0):

```
color_map = cv2.applyColorMap(img, cv2.COLORMAP_JET) # img.shape = (x, y)
cv2.imshow('colormap', color_map)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

more colors [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html)